# Proof of Euler's formula with Maclaurin Series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I was looking into the proof of Euler's formula based with Maclaurin Series and am confused on how one gets from ($\ast$) to ($\ast\ast$):

$$\begin{align*}\cos x & =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
\sin x & =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
\cos x+i\sin x & =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {i(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
 & =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {i^{2n} x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {i^{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \tag{$\ast$} \\
& =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(ix)^n}{n!} \tag{$\ast\ast$}\\
 & =e^{ix}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Please, avoid the use of images. Use Math Jax and type your equations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that

- $S_1:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n}=a_0+a_2+a_4+\ldots$.
- $S_2:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n+1}=a_1+a_3+a_5+\ldots$.
- $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots = S_1+S_2$.

Here:
\begin{align*}
\cos(x) + i\sin(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{i^{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!} +
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{i^{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
&=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(ix)^{2n}}{(2n)!} +
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(ix)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\\
&=
\sum_{n\text{ is even}} \dfrac{(ix)^{n}}{n!} +
\sum_{n\text{ is odd}}^{\infty}\dfrac{(ix)^{n}}{n!}
\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(ix)^n}{n!}
\end{align*}